# How to pin my window to the desktop (like rainmeter) and prevent minimizing by "Show Desktop"/win+d in qt/c++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, qt6

Does anybody know how to make a 'always-on-bottom" window without it minimizing to win+d, or a window pinned to the desktop?
qt and c++ solutions would be great.

I tried using a few things such as: SetWindowPos and setting qt flags to Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint
and SetParent as well as SetWindowLongPtr, but none of them seemed to work, did I use the wrong solution?

I am on Windows 11 btw.

Comment: According to your description, whether you want to make your Window a child control of the desktop window? If you want to develop widgets for Windows 11,there are better options available(winui3). According to the Blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683 As far as I'm concerned you couldn't use SetParent to create a parent/child relationship between windows which belong to different processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to be bottom-most, only the desktop listview is allowed to do that.

Anything trying to be a "desktop widget" involves hacks and you quickly run into [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

- On startup and when/after you are clicked, call `SetWindowPos` to order yourself to the bottom.

or

- Be a child of the desktop listview window. This involves `FindWindowEx`, `SetParent`, `WS_CHILD` and the undocumented [Explorer desktop window hierarchy](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/1036180/can-i-somehow-set-the-parent-of-shelldll-defview-h). [Good luck](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/856020/draw-behind-desktop-icons-in-windows-plus)...